# AssertJ assert either exception thrown or result

Tags: java, junit, future, assertions, assertj

I have a test case where i am using an executor service and invoking a number of callable threads. These threads may result in a successful call or may give an exception(which is an expected behavior). 
I need to assert that the future objects either throw an exception or return correct response.

```
for(Future<Resp> future : futureList) {
Assertions.assertThatThrownBy(() -> 
futureResponse.get()).isInstanceOf(ExecutionException.class);
// or
Assertions.assertThat(futureResponse.get()).isEqualTo(RespObj);
}
```

How do I assert this "OR" behavior?

Comment: for me, you test looks a bit weird... either you assert that it successed, either that it failed for a given case, but an implementation shouldn't really be allowed to fail or success without you to detect it... this test basically tells, try something and if it doesn't work, then it's ok. Not really any added value in this kind of test

Comment: @spi I am basically writing a integration test to check multiple parallel writes to a data store. In this i want to verify that only one of the calls should succeed, while all the others should fail.

Comment: then you should write it like that: count the number of success, count the number of failures, and assert there is exactly one success and n-1 failures. Else you will never notice when all fail.

Comment: Yes I have added the failureCount. Didnt include in this example though, as the question was how to assert either of the scenarios.

Comment: ok, that was not clear in the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `try catch` block:

```
  for(Future<Resp> future : futureList) {
        try {
            Assertions.assertThat(futureResponse.get()).isEqualTo(RespObj);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Assertions.assertThat(e).isInstanceOf(ExecutionException.class);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of an `ExecutionException` you might want to check its cause.

```
    for (Future<Resp> future : futureList) {
        try {
            Resp got = future.get();
            assertValidResp(got); // check normal behavior (eg not null)
        }
        catch (ExecutionException e) {
            Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            assertAcceptedException(cause); // check for expected abnormal behavior (eg instanceof check)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works for me. Thanks.! Both the answers are similar, so I am just accepting the first one.